# Working monitoring solution for Docker Containers and Swarm?

Tags: docker, monitoring, coreos, devops, docker-swarm

I'm looking for the monitoring solution for the web application, deployed as a Swarm of Docker containers spread through 7-10 VMs. High level requirements are:

- Configurable Web and REST interface to performance dashboard
- General performance metrics on VM levels (CPU/Memory/IO)
- Alerts when containers and/or VMs are going offline/restart
- Possibility to drill down into containers process activity when needed
- Host OS are CoreOS and Ubuntu

Any recommendations/best practices here?

NOTE: external Kibana installation is being used to collect application logs from Logstash agents deployed on VMs.

Comment: Just as an update from my side: after some research we're now testing setup with cAdvisors running on every cluster node and [Prometheus.io] as an back-end and analytics dashboard front-end. There are some other options we may look into, such as InfluxDB + Graphana, or Kubernetes + [Heapster](https://github.com/kubernetes/heapster).

Comment: I am looking for a swarm monitoring tool to. Any update on this?

Comment: @Yuri can you share some of your experience? I'm about to test the same cAdvisor on every node + prometheys setup. Any hints/resources?

Comment: The solution we used is similar to what's described here in this article https://stefanprodan.com/2016/a-monitoring-solution-for-docker-hosts-containers-and-containerized-services/

Works fine for us.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your requirements, it sounds like [Sematext Docker Agent](https://github.com/sematext/sematext-agent-docker) would be a good fit.  It runs as a tiny container on each Docker host and collects all host+containers metrics, events, and logs.  It can parse logs, route them, blacklist/whitelist them, has container auto-discovery, and so on.  In the end logs end up in [Logsene](http://sematext.com/logsene) and metrics and events end up in [SPM](http://sematext.com/spm), which gives you a single pane of glass sort of view into all your Docker ops bits, with alerting, anomaly detection, correlation, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Axibase Time-Series Database](https://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/writing-data/docker-cadvisor/) / Google Cadvisor / collectd stack.

*Disclosure: I work for the company that develops ATSD.*

- Deploy 1 Cadvisor container per VM to collect Docker container statistics. Cadvisor front-end allows you to view top container processes.
- Deploy 1 ATSD container to ingest data from multiple Cadvisor instances.
- Deploy collectd daemon on each VM to collect host statistics, configure collectd daemons to [stream data](https://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/writing-data/collectd/) into ATSD using write_atsd plugin.

Dashboards:

- Host:[image]
- Container: [image]

API / SQL:

- https://github.com/axibase/atsd/tree/master/api#api-categories

Alerts:

- ATSD comes with a built-in rule engine. You can configure a rule to watch when containers stops collecting data and trigger an email or system command.

Comment: Thanks Sergei - would this setup allow to get dynamic VM configuration, i.e. if new host joins the cluster with cAdvisor on it, could ATSD pick it up automatically?

Comment: Correct, as you launch cadvisor container on new hosts just make sure to point its atsd storage driver to the central ATSD.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently evaluating bosun with scollector + cAdvisor support. Look ok so far.

Edit:
It should meet all the listed requirements and a little bit more. :)